# Boost shared_ptr to array, getting size

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, shared-ptr

Ok I am new to this approach, so it may be wrong. But basically I want to have a `shared_ptr` to an array. With Boost 1.53+, it seems that there's no need to use `make_shared_array`. Anyway I don't even want to allocate it- but create it from a pointer and a size, and just let it be managed.

So:

```
// I have a (char* p) to the array, and a (size_t sz) specifying the length of it

// shall I create a shared_ptr like this...
boost::shared_ptr<char[]> sp(p, sz); // is this even right?

// now, how can I get the size of the structure? (assuming sz is out of scope)
```

Is it lost? Shall I then wrap everything up in another class that also remembers the size of the stored array?

Comment: Why not use `boost::array<char, sz>`?

Comment: Assume I have no control, I just get the char* and the size_t of it... or are you suggesting to create the boost::array container from the pointer?

Comment: As your example suggests you need an array of `char`s, why bother to create a `shared_ptr` and not just use `boost::array` if you know the size of the buffer beforehand or use a `std::string` or `std::vector` if you need a dynamic array (i.e., size is specified at runtime).

Comment: Let's assume that I get the pointer to the buffer and its size from code that I don't have control over, i.e. a decompression library implemented in C. I want this specific method to make the shared_ptr to the buffer to make it available to other objects after the expiration of the object that creates it. But the original code that allocated the memory is that decompression library.

Comment: Then using `shared_ptr` like this you have a serious problem. If the buffer is allocated in C (I assume using `malloc`), then the `shared_ptr` needs a custom deleter. Generally, is not a good idea to initialize smart pointers with memory you didn't allocate your self.

Comment: You're right... I just consider too expensive and absurd having to copy the memory into a new buffer allocated by my code. So I'll look into implementing the custom deleter that `free()`s.

Comment: Is there some reason you're avoiding [`boost::shared_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm)?  You will have to track the size yourself (or better yet switch to `std::vector`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
boost::shared_ptr<char[]> sp(new char[100]);
```

But you'll need to manually keep track of the size (100 in this case).

Comment: Ok, imagine that I don't create the array. It's already allocated.

Comment: I guess that you're suggesting my first thought solution to wrap it into a class that takes care of the size...